# How do I group many interfaces into a common single interface?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, polymorphism, encapsulation

EDIT: The simple answer to my question is that Java allows one interface to extend multiple other interfaces. This is what answers my logical question of how you group interfaces together in a common interface. This answer did not appear in the dupe question. Also the question was different, it was not about creating interface groups.

Is there a reason in Java you cannot define one interface as implementing other interfaces? The answer I've seen and been dissatisfied with is that "interfaces themselves don't contain implementation, so how could an interface implement other other interfaces?" Well, that's a weak answer in my opinion, because its more a nod to English semantics than it is logical interpretation of the scenario. The logical interpretation of the scenario is since we can define classes to implement many interfaces, why can't we define an interface that itself represents a collection of interfaces.

Suppose you have many classes that you want to each implement a large, common set of many interfaces. As it currently stands, you'd have to explicitly write out the list for each class. This means that if later you had to add another interface to your list of many, you'd have to modify each class. Having all the interfaces consolidated in one "super interface" would allow the programmer to make the change in only one place.

And before you answer "make an abstract superclass that implements the list of interfaces, and have all your subclasses extend that superclass", keep in mind you cannot assume these classes do not already extend classes. One of the whole benefits of the implements keyword is so that you can adapt a class without having to change its taxonomy, right?

I guess the long story short is: Why can't programmers define interfaces that are just groups of other interfaces? Or, maybe the better question is: If I can't define an interface as implementing other interfaces, HOW can I define interfaces that are groups of other interfaces?

For those of you that prefer code, what I'm asking is why instead of doing this...

```
public class Foo extends ParentClass1 implements IBar1, IBar2, IBar3{
}

public class Baz extends ParentClass2 implements IBar1, IBar2, IBar3{
}
```

...wouldn't it make more sense for Java to allow this:

```
public interface IAllBar implements IBar1, IBar2, IBar3{
}

public class Foo extends ParentClass1 implements IAllBar{
}

public class Baz extends ParentClass2 implements IAllBar{
}
```

That way, later, if I create IBar4 I only have to modify IAllBar.java instead of Foo.java AND Baz.java.

Edit: So according to below answers I can define IAllBar to EXTEND all those interfaces and I'll get exactly what I want. I'm glad some people are willing to read an entire post before jumping to the bottom to post mean responses.

Comment: The old question has a sufficient answer.

Comment: That's third question today, that sounds like "I've read documentation and it's clearly stated there, that some programming language does not support feature I need. Why is life so cruel to me?". This is Q&A site, not discussion forum.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The site guidelines say I may reask a question if the answers to existing questions are not correct or satisfactory.

Comment: You guys don't get to decide if an answer is sufficient. If I did my due diligence and still couldn't find the answer, I'm allowed to post a question. If you guys had bothered to actually read my post, you'd see that I wasn't really asking about use of the implements keyword, I was asking HOW DO YOU GROUP INTERFACES INTO ONE COMMON INTERFACE? The answer is "Use multiple inheritance". Which was finally given to me below. Please do NOT comment, vote down, or mark as duplicate a post which you are not willing to read thoroughly.

Comment: @user2522434 Nothing like this happens, when you formulate your question correctly.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and close this.  Defacing your question doesn't help your case, and the original question seems to sufficiently cover this ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an interface that's a collection of other interfaces. Its called extending an interface. You can extend multiple interfaces.

As for why you can't define methods in an interface, it's how Java interfaces were defined. And the problem you speak of are the consequences of single inheritance.

However you will be pleased to know that in the new upcoming Java 8 there's an feature called Virtual Extension Methods which addresses the large code base problems you speak of.

Personally I think it's useful in legacy code bases for quick refactoring, but if the system is well designed you should be able to get rid of the default implementations later. And overusing this feature will only result in all the disadvantages of multiple inheritance.

Comment: When you extend multiple interfaces its essentially grouping them to one interface isn't it?

Comment: I did not realize you could extend multiple interfaces! How come this is not then the answer on the other similar questions??

Comment: Dunno. Go ask the dudes who answered :-)

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces cannot be instantiated—they can only be implemented by classes or extended by other interfaces.

I believe what you should do is extend interfaces.

You could do this as shown below:

```
public interface ManBearPig implements Man, Bear, Pig {
    //interface body
}
```

You could then implement ManBearPig where you need it.

The thing you need to keep in mind is that interfaces support multiple inheritance.

To understand this consider the idea that interfaces Man, Bear, and Pig might each have the method walk() included within them.

If you were to implement ManBearPig in a class and call the walk() method it would implement the walk method of Man, Bear, and pig simultaneously.

Comment: YES this is the answer. I did not know about multiple inheritance for interfaces

Comment: No problem I learned a lot researching this. I cant stress enough that you need to look at each interface you are grouping and make sure thier methods dont overlap in such a way that would break your application.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, your problem statement is:

> **How to design a Type hierarchy where a group of *Classes* implement same set of *Interfaces* and a number of behaviors exposed by the interfaces have common implementation.**

This kind of design problem can be solved in Java in the following way (explaining by your example code)

```
public abstract class AbstractAllBar implements IBar1, IBar2, IBar3{

/* Provide implementations of methods whose behavior remains unchanges for all of it's children classes.*/

}
```

Now this abstract class can be extended by the classes who have common set of behaviors as defined by the abstract class *AbstractAllBar*.

```
public class ParentClass1 extends AbstractAllBar {

.......    

}

public class ParentClass2 extends AbstractAllBar {

.......    

}

public class Foo extends ParentClass1 {

}

public class Baz extends ParentClass2 {

}
```

This kind of abstract classes provide ***Skeleton Implementation***. Examples of ***Skeleton Implementation*** can be found in *Collection API*. You can refer source code of *[AbstractList](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/AbstractList.java#AbstractList)* and *AbstractSet* to make it more clear.

Comment: Why do you assume that I can modify ParentClass1 and ParentClass2? That was the whole point of me including those in the example. The answer as it turns out is that I can use multiple inheritance when defining the IBarAll interface. Literally, if I just replace implements with extends, then it is correct.

Comment: Skeleton classes are one of the best solution for this kind of problems. If you don not have control on ParentClass1 and ParentClass2 (i.e. these classes are part of any library), the only option you have is to implement each method defined in interfaces in all sub classes. If you can share more about ParentClass1 and ParentClass2, I can explore more options.